# how to build andoid image and emulator from source?

Tags: android, linux, image, ubuntu, emulation

i want to build android image and emulator from source code.  i'm working in a VM (virtualbox), so i'm open to any version of whatever linux (preferably ubuntu) someone wants to suggest.

i'm looking at
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu/+/gradle_0.14.4/docs/BUILDING.TXT
and
https://source.android.com/docs/setup/download/downloading

but everything i do seems to wind up with a problem somewhere.  i've run into problems with python2 vs python3, 32 clib being missing, jack server missing, whatever, you name it.  my current try, the "repo sync" doesn't seem to pick up the "external/qemu" mentioned in "BUILDING.TXT" so there's literally nothing to build.

i'm tearing my hair out.

where can i find, in 2023, a set of step by step WORKING instructions on how to build the android emulator and an android image, from source, on any version of ubuntu linux?

tried multiple versions of Linux, multiple repo sync incantations, everything.  i just need instructions that WORK, and produce viable emulator and image artifacts.

Comment: just tried following this.  no joy.  lots of stuff downloaded, nothing created, nothing to build.  *sigh*  https://www.kodeco.com/10197539-building-the-android-open-source-project